# How do I resolve this LoRA loading error?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm trying to run through [the  LoRA tutorial](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/training/lora#text-to-image). I've gotten the dataset pulled down, trained it and have checkpoints on disk (in the form of several subdirectories and `.safetensors` files).

The last part is trying to run inference. In particular,

```
from diffusers import AutoPipelineForText2Image
import torch

pipeline = AutoPipelineForText2Image.from_pretrained("runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5", torch_dtype=torch.float16).to("cuda")
pipeline.load_lora_weights("path/to/lora/model", weight_name="pytorch_lora_weights.safetensors")
```

However, on my local when I try to run that `load_lora_weights` line, I get

```
>>> pipeline.load_lora_weights("path/to/my/lora", weight_name="pytorch_lora_weights.safetensors")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/to/my/site-packages/diffusers/loaders/lora.py", line 107, in load_lora_weights
    raise ValueError("PEFT backend is required for this method.")
ValueError: PEFT backend is required for this method.
>>>
```

I have PEFT installed, but there don't seem to be instructions calling for me to do anything else about it in order to load a LoRA.

What am I doing wrong here? If the answer is "nothing, this is the 'it's an experimental API' note coming back to bite you", are there any workarounds?

Comment: This might be a totally simple thing, did you actually change `path/to/lora/model` to the path to your LoRA model ?

Comment: @KaranShishoo - Yup; it was a local path on my machine in the raw transcript; `path/to/lora/model` is an after-the-fact anonymization :p Fair question though.